# <!-- ko if: false --> throws Cannot read property '__ko__1380676672381' of null

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-sortable

### Issue example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TJ2f/3/)

**Problem:**
If `!!$data.Visible() == false` then it throws this error

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__ko__1380676672381' of null knockout-2.3.0.debug.js:578
```

Error occurs here:

```
getAll: function (node, createIfNotFound) {
            var dataStoreKey = node[dataStoreKeyExpandoPropertyName];
```

Code:

```
<!-- ko if: !!$data.Visible() -->
    <div class="row-column" data-bind="text: $parent[$data.Key], attr: { style: 'width: ' + $data.Width() + 'px' }"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

My previous answer was incorrect because the sortable binding needs to be able to update the array. So the solution instead is to not use a virtual element for the `if` binding.

```
<div data-bind="if: $data.Visible()">
    <div>Im visible</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/5TJ2f/6/

References: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14219177/1287183, https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable/issues/58

Comment: If you check this example http://jsfiddle.net/5TJ2f/5/ , you can see I cannot get back anything in `console` is droped error.

Comment: Yes this would be the solution. But I just don't understand if this error is intended or it's something `knockout-sortable` team needs to fix or implement.

Comment: Big thanks on that last link, now I understand why it's not working.